# Can't install mysql gem on Percona-XtraDB-Cluster

Tags: mysql, ruby, percona

I saw there few topics about this problem, but none of them solved my problem.

So. Platform is CentOS 6.6. I have installed Percona-XtraDB-Cluster, their mysql-libs and their devel packages.
Also i have there ruby 2.0.0 and rubygems 2.4.3. Now i am trying to install mysql gem. What i am getting:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing mysql:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141114-16854-1fyrg9v.rb extconf.rb checking for
>   mysql_ssl_set()... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile
>   due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or
>   headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need
>   configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --with-opt-include
>     --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include    --with-opt-lib
>     --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby     --with-mysql-config
>     --without-mysql-config
>   /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The
>   compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You
>   have to install development tools first.  from
>   /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in`try_link0'     from
>   /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `try_link'  from
>   /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:720:in`try_func'  from
>   /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1004:in `block in
>   have_func'    from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in`
>   block in checking_for'   from
>   /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in
>   postpone'     from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in`
>   open'    from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block
>   in postpone'  from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in`
>   open'    from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in
>   `postpone'    from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in`
>   checking_for'    from
>   /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1003:in `have_func'    from
>   extconf.rb:45:in`'
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0/mysql-2.9.1/gem_make.out

Any of described solutions, which i found on the web didn't help me, so, maybe someone had similar problems with this Percona cluster and ruby-2.0.0 and gem mysql-2.9.1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need development libraries for the Ruby gem MySQL with SSL:

Try each of these:

```
yum install gcc

yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-server

yum install openssl openssl-devel  

yum install ruby-devel
```

Then try installing the newer `mysql2` gem:

```
 gem install mysql2 --version '>=0.3.17'
```

Sensu expects SSL, so it is good to have it. The Sensu documentation says " It is possible to use Sensu without SSL, however, it is heavily discouraged. The following instructions use a tool to generate self-signed OpenSSL certificates". Read about how to enable SSL here:

```
http://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/certificates#documentation
```

If you want SSL, you may want to ensure that your database does have SSL enabled:

```
> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_openssl  | YES   |
| have_ssl      | YES   |
...
```

You wrote in the comment that you can't install `mysql-devel` and `mysql-server` because they will conflict with percona. My guess is that the error is the older `mysql` gem and/or the need for SSL.

If you are using `rvm`, it can also cause these kinds of glitches. You may want to try `ruby-install` and installing the current ruby. This may bring in the dependencies you need. If you want, you can use `ruby-install` in a custom directory, like this:

```
 $ ruby-install ruby 2.1.5 --install-dir ~/foo/bar/
```

If you are using `sudo gem install`, it can also cause glitches for native gems. You may want to try becoming root, and using the actual root environment, and the root ruby version, and double-checking that the ruby version is what you expect, like this:

```
 $ sudo su - 
 # which ruby
 # ruby --version
 # gem install mysql2 --version '>=0.3.17'
```

Comment: I can not install mysql-devel and mysql-server, because those components will conflict with percona packages. Also ssl is disabled, but how it can be related to gem? For now i don't run any script to access to MySql. I just want to install gem. Also, with attempt to install mysql - i'm getting this string in error: checking for mysql_ssl_set()... *** extconf.rb failed ***; and with mysql2 - this: checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***